# How do I refactor similar methods to eliminate duplicate setup and exception handling?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, refactoring

#### Context:

I consume a ERP WebService exposing N methods like:

```
FunctionNameResponse FunctionName(FunctionNameQuery query)
```

I made a functional wrapper in order to:

- Get rid off wrapper object `FunctionNameResponse` and `FunctionNameQuery`, that every method has.
- One instance of the WebService for all the program.
- Investigate and log error in the wrapper.
- Investigate Slow running and Soap envelope with `IClientMessageInspector`

#### Duplicated code:

For each of the methods of the WebService I end up with around thirty lines of code with only 3 distinct words. Type response, type query, method name.

```
public FooResponse Foo(FooQuery query)  
{  
    // CheckWebServiceState();  
    FooResponse result = null;  
    try  
    {   
        result =  
                WSClient  
                .Foo(query)  
                .response;  
    }  
    catch (Exception e)  
    {  
        // SimpleTrace();  
        // SoapEnvelopeInterceptorTrace();                 
        // TimeWatch_PerformanceIEndpointBehaviorTrace();  
    }  
    return result;
}
```

I would like to reduce those repetition. In order to :

- Make it easier to add a Method;
- Avoid copy pasting programming with no need to understand what you are doing.
- Easier to add specific catch  and new test without the need to copy past in every method.

The following code work and exist only in the imaginary realm. It's a not functional sketch of my solution using my limited understanding.

```
public class Demo
{
    public enum WS_Method
    {
        Foo,Bar,FooBar
    }
    public class temp
    {
        public Type Query { get; set; }
        public Type Response { get; set; }
        public WS_Method MethodName { get; set; }
    }
    public static IEnumerable<temp> TestFunctions =>
        new List<temp>
        {
            new temp{Query=typeof(FooQuery), Response=typeof(FooResponse), MethodName=WS_Method.Foo },
            new temp{Query=typeof(BarQuery), Response=typeof(BarResponse), MethodName=WS_Method.Bar },
            new temp{Query=typeof(FooBarQuery), Response=typeof(FooBarResponse), MethodName=WS_Method.FooBar },
        };
    public static void Run()
    {   // Exemple of consuming the method 
        var input = new BarQuery { Bar_Label = "user input", Bar_Ig = 42 };

        BarResponse result = Execute<BarQuery, BarResponse>(input);
    }
    public static T2 Execute<T1,T2>(T1 param) {
        //Get temp line where Query type match Param Type.
        var temp = TestFunctions.Single(x => x.Query == typeof(T1));
        var method = typeof(DemoWrapper).GetMethod(temp.MethodName.ToString(), new Type[] { typeof(T1) });
        var wsClient = new DemoWrapper();

        T2 result = default(T2);
        try
        {
            result =
                    method
                        .Invoke(wsClient, new object[] { param })
                        .response;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // SimpleTrace();
            // SoapEnvelopeInterceptorTrace();               
            // TimeWatch_PerformanceIEndpointBehaviorTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

I know the reflection is heavy and perhaps it's not the right way to achieve this refactoring. So the question is:

#### How do I refactor those function?

attachment : Live demo https://dotnetfiddle.net/aUfqNp.

Comment: Why not still have the `FooResponse Foo(FooQuery)` method but have it call `Execute<FooQuery, FooRespoince>` as for the method called you'd need a `Func<T1, T2>` and you could pass it `query => WSClient.Foo(query).response;`

Comment: @juharr, so I'll still have a ton of redudant code for each method, But I will have a nicer way to call it? If I want to add a catch for a specific exception I need to regex my code to not have to make 80+ copy past.

Comment: The methods would be about the same amount of code lines as that List you currently have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this scenario:

- You have a larger block of code which is mostly repeated
- The only difference is a smaller unit of code that's called inside the larger block

You can refactor this by passing the smaller unit of code as a `Func` or `Action` as a parameter to the larger function.

In that case your larger function looks like this:

```
public TResponse GetResponse<TResponse>(Func<TResponse> responseFunction)
{
    var result = default(TResponse);
    try
    {
        result = responseFunction();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // SimpleTrace();  
        // SoapEnvelopeInterceptorTrace();                 
        // TimeWatch_PerformanceIEndpointBehaviorTrace();  
    }
    return result;
}
```

The individual functions which call it look like this, without all the repeated code:

```
public FooResponse Foo(FooQuery query)
{
    return GetResponse(() => WSClient.Foo(query));
}
```

Comment: Since there's no common code working on the query this is a cleaner approach.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach where you keep the methods but have them all call a method that handles the duplication.

```
public class Demo
{
    private _wsClient = new DemoWrapper();

    public static void Run()
    {   // Exemple of consuming the method 
        var input = new BarQuery { Bar_Label = "user input", Bar_Ig = 42 };

        BarResponse result = Bar(input);
    }

    public FooResponse Foo(FooQuery foo) =>
        Execute(foo, query => _wsClient.Foo(query));

    public BarResponse Bar(BarQuery bar) =>
        Execute(bar, query => _wsClient.Bar(query));

    public FooBarResponse FooBar(FooBarQuery fooBar) =>
        Execute(fooBar, query => _wsClient.FooBar(query));

    private static TResponse Execute<TQuery ,TResponse>(
        TQuery param, Func<TQuery, TResponse> getResponse) 
    {
        //Get temp line where Query type match Param Type.
        var result = default(TResponse);
        try
        {
            result = getResponse(query);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // SimpleTrace();
            // SoapEnvelopeInterceptorTrace();               
            // TimeWatch_PerformanceIEndpointBehaviorTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok my brain is dead using reflexion trying to solve the issue. it's far mor clearer that way. I really didn't saw it that way when you commented